# Responsive bootstrap issue

Tags: responsive

I have jquery datatable with server side processing. It has select tag with different options append to it. On desktop, it is displaying drop-down with all items but on small screen it is collapsing all columns but drop-down is not displaying drop-down items. I’m using responsive bootstrap.min.css and JS as well. Can anyone help please.

Comment: share some code snippets in codepen or jsfiddle to better understand your issue.